# Using JSP to add selected in html option, without error but not displaying anything on screen

Tags: jsp

This is the original code without error:

```
<option   value=<%=eventFields[0]%>  ><%=eventFields[1]%> <%=eventFields[2]%> </option>
```

Then I try to add the If condition then add the selected, but then screen shows nothing but no error:

```
<option   value=<%=eventFields[0]%>  <%if((rs.getString(0))=="206"){%> selected <%}%>><%=eventFields[1]%> <%=eventFields[2]%> </option>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Take note that String comparisons in Java won't work this way:

```
<%if((rs.getString(0))=="206"){%>
```

I suggest you replace that with:

```
<%if((rs.getString(0)).equals("206")){%>
```